# Does enlarge person add more effects than described in its description?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, creature-size

When subjected to the Enlarge Person spell, a creature takes a +2 to strength, a -2 to dex, and a -1 to ac and attack due to its size. However, page 290 of the monster manual has a table that shows the effects of changing a creature's size to its stats.

It states that, for example, a medium creature that becomes large receives +8 str, -2 dex, +4 con, +2 natural armour and -1 ac/atk. Are these changes applied to a creature that is enlarged on top of the normal effects of the spell, due to it gaining a size category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

That table is part of “Chapter 4: Improving Monsters” and its changes are specific to monster-creation math when designing a new, more powerful creature based on an existing one.

That table is not a generic table of the general effects of changes in size during play.